# jquery extend: what's happening here?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created an object constructor according to the layout proposed by Douglas Crockford in his book "[Javascript: the good parts](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596517748.do)".

This constructor returns a `that` object, after adding to it various members and methods.
One of these methods is clone function, in which JQuery `extend` is utilized to deep-copy the `that` object.

However, after creating a clone, something strange happens - modifying the clone's members doesn't seem to affect the `that` object from within its methods.

You can see a live example on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sangil/cfqLmume/1/)

code:

```
var ctr = function() {
    var that = {};

    that.a = 0;

    that.f = function() {
        return that.a;
    };

    that.clone = function() {
        return jQuery.extend(true, {}, that);
    }

    return that;
}

var obj1 = ctr();
var obj2 = obj1.clone();

obj2.a = 5; 

// Why are these values different????
console.log(obj2.a);        // prints '5', as expected
console.log(obj2.f());      //prints '0'!!!! WHY??
```

If we use `this` instead of `that` in the JQuery extend arguments, it works as expected.

What's going on here?

Comment: Because `that` is a permanent reference to the original object, and the `f` function will never lose sight of that object. So your `f` function is basically doing `obj1.a` when it does `that.a`. In other words, both `obj1` and `obj2` share the same `f` function, and that `f` function is referencing `obj1` *(`that`)*.

Comment: so is there any way to create a copy whose methods reference the new 'that'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`that.f` is closing over the `that` of `o1` and that closure is being copied when you use extend.

```
// from your updated JSFiddle
var o1 = ctr();
var o2 = o1.clone();

o2.a = 5;

// Why are these values different????
alert('Direct=' + o2.a + ', via Method=' + o2.f());
// prints 'Direct=5, via Method=0'

o1.a = 3;
alert('Direct=' + o2.a + ', via Method=' + o2.f());
// prints 'Direct=5, via Method=3'
```